# How to login to account with only address and passphrase?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, recovery

I downloaded ethereum years ago. I forget which brokerage I used, but I created an ethereum account with the geth console and sent money to the address.

I recorded the address and am fairly sure I know the passphrase since I have written down 6 random words beside my address. My computer crashed sometime between then and now.

With my address, with my known passphrase, how do I access my wallet / account?